# Terraform custom provider access to lifecycle metadata

Tags: go, terraform

I am writing a custom provider and am trying to figure out how to get access to the lifecycle data in the .tf file in my go code.

```
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [
           "member_list"
        ]
    }
```

I'm digging through the code, but so far no luck in finding it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need access to it in your provider? That's a core Terraform thing so I don't think the providers will have an easy way to get hold of that.

Comment: Yeah I do not believe `lifecycle` is supposed to be accessible from the `provider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lifecycle` contains settings that are use by Terraform Core during graph construction. All of the behaviors modeled there are handled by Terraform Core itself, not by the provider.

There is therefore no way for a provider to access the settings in there. In the case of `ignore_changes`, that is applied after the change plan is generated by the provider by discarding the planned changes for any argument mentioned in the `ignore_changes` list.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.